# Customize bootstrap column arrangement on desktop

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap v3.1.1

---

When the browser window is <992px, the divs arrange:

[ left ]

[ main ]

[ right ]

---

How could I make them arrange like this instead?

[ main ]

[ left ][ right ]

*main centered and left & right centered below it

---

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-2 column left" style="background: rgb(108,108,240)></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 column main" style="background: rgb(108,108,240)"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 column right" style="background: rgb(108,108,240)></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the column width for smaller devices using `col-sm-*` or `col-xs-*`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 column left" style="background: rgb(108,108,240)"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 column main" style="background: rgb(108,108,240)"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 column right" style="background: rgb(108,108,240)"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

But the largest column (main) would need to be first in the list of divs

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TshU2/)